# Calculate the mean from excel sheet for specific rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing, mean

Hello guys! I am struggling to calculate the mean of certain rows from
an excel sheet using python. In particular, I would like to calculate the mean for every three rows starting from the first  three and then moving to the next three and so on. My excel sheet contains 156 rows of data.
My data sheet looks like this:
[image]

```
And this is my code: 
import numpy 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("My Excel.xlsx")
x = df.iloc[[0,1,2], [9,10,11]].mean()
print(x)
```

To sum up, I am trying to calculate the mean of Part 1 Measurements 1 (rows 1,2,3) and the mean of Part 2
Measurements 1 (rows 9,10,11) using one line of code, or some kind of index. I am expecting to receive two lists of numbers, one that stands for the mean of Part 1 Measurement 1 (rows 1,2,3) and the other for the mean of Part 2 Measurements 1 (rows 10,11,12). I am also familiar with the fact that python counts row number one as 0. The index should have a form of n+1.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could (e.g.) generate a list for each mean you want to calculate:

```
x1, x2 = list(df.iloc[[0,1,2]].mean()), list(df.iloc[[9,10,11]].mean())
```

Or you could also generate a list of lists:

```
x = [list(df.iloc[[0,1,2]].mean()), list(df.iloc[[9,10,11]].mean())]
```

Comment: The second approach looks really nice. I've tried it but I am getting 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'.

Comment: I forgot a bracket behind "mean()", its edited now.

Comment: I have noticed it but still getting the same

Comment: x1, x2 = list(df.iloc[[0,1,2]]).mean(), list(df.iloc[[9,10,11]]).mean(). I have installed statistics lib.

Comment: There is still no bracket behind mean() in what you commented

Comment: I am very sorry but I am new. The list syntax requires a bracket behind mean?

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks a lot for your assistance. Have a nice day!

Comment: If I am dealing with a lot of rows how could I make my code more efficient instead of x1, x2 etc?

Comment: I would suggest to try something and ask a new question if you stuck somewhere